# Как выбрать рандомное фото (jpg) из папки \arts и отправить его в канал откуда вызывалась команда?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Сам бот находится рядом с папкой arts. Для удобства переименовал все фото в 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg и так далее.
Структура тела бота:

```
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
client.run('ajhsfsafhdjfsjafsdfjsfjhdfj')
```

Comment: фрагменты самого кода не прикрепил, ибо там ничего нет. Одна структура. Я понял только, как вывести список всех файлов в папке \arts.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob, random

files = glob.glob("/arts/*.jpg")
random_files = list()
for _ in range(1, random.randint(2, 12)):
    random_files.append(random.choice(files))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]